# Xamarin Forms está removendo o espaço entre as palavras em tempo de execução

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin-forms

Estou trabalhando em um projeto com Xamarin Forms Visual Studio. Ao executar o projeto para o iOS, funciona perfeitamente, mas quando executo o mesmo projeto para Android as frases aparecem todas juntas. Ex.:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label
        Text="Aguarde! Processando..."
        TextColor="{x:StaticResource ColorPrimary}"
        FontSize="Small"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
    <ActivityIndicator
        Color="{x:StaticResource ColorPrimary}"
        IsRunning="True"/>
</StackLayout>
```

O resultado é:

[image: Imagem]

Isso acontece para todas as frases dos arquivos XAML.
Se no XAML esta `<Label Text="Xamarin Forms Visual Studio"/>`, quando executo fica XamarinFormsVisualStudio.

Inicio do XAML: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`;
Já verifiquei a tag `xml:space="preserve"` nos arquivos de resource;
Já tentei inserir esta mesma tag direto no arquivo XAML e nada.

Alguma sugestão?

Obrigado!!!

Comment: Cara... Muito estranho mesmo! Você já tentou a solução mágica: deletar `obj` e `bin`, clean e rebuild?

Comment: Sim, foi uma das primeiras coisa que fiz. Inclusive, essa dica é muito boa mesmo, resolveu vários outros problemas que tive durante o desenvolvimento. De qualquer forma obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu usei o site IcoMoon para gerar um arquivo com mais opções de fontes para incluir em meu projeto. No iOS funcionou normalmente, mas no Android apresentava esse problema.

Consegui resolver removendo o arquivo gerado pelo IcoMoon e adicionando no lugar um arquivo que baixei na internet da FontAwesome, aí passou a funcionar corretamente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]